# How to release excel process?

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I'm using the Excel interop and it seems to be creating a process every time I call

```
new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
```

And never ending the process even though I call

```
xlApp.Quit();
```

How can I get the processes to end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you releasing all of your references?  (Which means you have to save them in the first place).

For example here's what's in my dispose from some excel interop():

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(!this.disposed)
        {
            if(cell != null)
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(cell);

            if(cells != null)
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(cells);

            if(worksheet != null)
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(worksheet);

            if(worksheets != null)
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(worksheets);

            if (workbook != null)
            {
                workbook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workbook);
            }

            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workbooks);
            xlApp.Quit();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp);

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            disposed = true;
        }
    }
```

(Not sure if this is perfect but it worked for me!)

Comment: My objects were locally scoped, so I put that in a finally, but it works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Excel won't quit if you don't release used COM Objects.

[This Answer should provide more information.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c/158752#158752)

Comment: Yeah, that's where I got my solution from, mainly.  Although I found just doing what the chosen answer selected wasn't enough, I had to put the Close(), the Quit() and the GC calls in there too.  Difficult to get rid of, those damn Excel spreadsheets!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this happens because you did modify the document and Excel is waiting for some saving. 
Try something like:

```
ObjWorkBook.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAction.xlDoNotSaveChanges, 
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

before quitting