# C# Excel workbook is closed, but cannot move the file

Tags: c#, excel

I am opening an Excel file via

```
app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
wb = app.Workbooks.Open(fromFile, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Then I am manipulating the cells, which works fine. I save the file to antother Folder, than I opened it in.

```
wb.SaveAs(toFile, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
```

I Close the app and the workbook:

```
wb.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
app.Quit();
```

When I now want to move the original file by File.Move(), I get the error:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
>
> process.

Am I missing something?

edit:

Thank you very much guys. It has been the missing release of the objects.

```
Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(object)
```

edit 2:

Well, but now I could run it once and now I always get the error:

> This file is currently not available for use on this computer.

Combined with a COMException

> The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

Comment: This might help: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5e680538-ed9b-4894-b358-bb72a9b7f531/the-process-cannot-access-the-file-it-is-being-used-by-another-process-to-close-excel-file-before?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Are you calling `File.Move` just directly after `app.Quit`?

Comment: Press [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[Del] and make sure there's no Excel process locking the file.

Comment: I even wrote the move part into another Action and created a new button, I first have to click. When I don't manipulate the file before, moving works.

Comment: there is still an Excel process open in the task manager, which shouldnt be.

How can I Close it?

Comment: Did you try this?  https://sayanghosh.wordpress.com/2009/02/04/a-com-heartbreak-microsoft-office-interop-excel-workbook-and-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use

```
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Object_to_be_released)
```

for all objects used in the interop service.

```
_xlApp.Quit();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_xlApp);
```

Comment: hmm. Is it a Standard Namespace? I can't find it, to use it.

Comment: its in `using System.Runtime.InteropServices`

Comment: As i edited. Now I can run it perfectly once, but now it seems that the file cannot be read again.

Comment: According to the edits of your post, those are different questions from the one you originally asked.  If you google those errors you will find lots of articles that deal with those same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Before you move excel file from source folder to destination folder you need to release all the references related to excel file.
References which you want to release is listed in answer given by Grand Crofton
Please refer his answer: [How to release excel process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814026/how-to-release-excel-process)

Comment: As i edited. Now I can run it perfectly once, but now it seems that the file cannot be read again.